# How can I contain an absolute positioned div in a relative positioned div?

Tags: html, css, css-position

How can I contain an absolute positioned `div` inside a relative positioned `div`? For example, a structure like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.contentWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
  <div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="content">Looong text here...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Will result as the height of the `contentWrapper` to be 0 (when element inspected) and the div with the content class will not show.

Is there a way to apply clearfix method for absolute positioned elements inside relative ones?

What I am trying to do here is to avoid the `Looooong text` from expanding the wrapper (wrapper has a dynamic width, cannot be fixed). `contentWrapper` contains the text and wraps it, also it fills the width of the parent wrapper so that it does not get expanded. The only problem is the height of the contentWrapper is 0, and the text is not showing.

Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, you can only use a clearfix to clear floated elements.

Answer (score 0):

If the only element inside your relatively positioned container is positioned absolute, you will have to specify a height on the container. The problem is that `position:absolue` removes the element from the content flow, so the container doesn't recognize the absolutely positioned element's height.

Comment: When I specify the height, it works. However the height is dynamic, so I cannot fix it. And I really dont want to use jQuery for this.