# How can I prevent elements moving due to absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Is there any solution available to stop elements that don't have a predefined height from moving up when an position absolute is used in another div?

this is what it looks like with the heights defined.

http://jsfiddle.net/77tsq/ : DEMO

```
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background:green;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background:blue;

}   

.test { position:relative;
  width: 600px;
height:200px;
float:left;
 clear:both;
 background:pink;
}

.clear { clear:both;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="relative">
<div class="absolute">

</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="test">
</div>
```

But when remove the heights it looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/77tsq/1/ - No heights

Comment: something that is positioned relatively will avoid conflict with anything.. your test div has a position relative, so it will always try to avoid something... position absolute will go wherever it pleases. My question for you is.. what are you trying to do with these divs?

Comment: I also believe this may be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752479/absolute-positioned-div-inside-a-relative-positioned-div

Comment: Well my friend, I have been trying to get a sticky menu working that changes on scroll .. and things were messing up. So I tried to recreate everything with no javascript etc. just plain divs and it seems that elements shifts..

even when I use fixed things screw up.

I figured that a div below the two would still float below but it moves up

Comment: Positioning, more specifically absolute positioning, is very sporadic.. undefined and can go anyway/where is pleases. I would suggest floating if you can.

Comment: The problem is that there is nothing in the first div. Well, only an absolutely positioned div, but that doesn't count. So, if you don't give the first div a height explicitly, the height is zero. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is that you want your `.test <div>` to remain at the bottom of the `.relative div`.

But it not working because `.relative div` is parent div for `.absolute div` and *when the parent div has no defined height property then it has `height: auto` css property by default. So it will have the height of its child div. But When you set `position: absolute` on a child div, the child div becomes independent of the parent div(no longer acts as child) so you are over-riding/breaking this default behavior.* So the parent will no longer take care of its child div when the child has `position: absolute` and The child will be absolutely positioned over all other div's as independent div.

In your case the child div i.e `.absolute div` is placed over the other div's leaving the space below it empty for other divs so other div's can take the  background place below it. As the parent `.relative div` is empty and it has no defined height property and it is no longer taking height of its children .absolute div so its height has become zero. Similarly `.clear div` is also empty and with no defined height property and  thus  has zero height. So as a result .test div takes the top place. So it will not work as long as you use `position:absolute` for `.absolute div` or you do not define height for `.relative div`. So we have to find an alternate solution for it.

So, if you want to make it work, you have two alternate solutions:

- **remove the css properties `position:absolute;top:120px;` from the child .absolute div  and add css properties `float:right; margin-top: 120px;` to position it as you desired.** check the result here:https://jsfiddle.net/22namfpn/1/ (The `.relative div` will still not be visible as long as it is empty or has no defined height property)

OR

- set a custom height (`height: 400px;` or any suitable height) on the parent `.relative div`(as you already tried here:http://jsfiddle.net/77tsq/)

(Sorry as this answer is too late but I think it may guide/help you and others understand that why your code was not working as you desired).